# Functional Components in React

Tags: reactjs

Tengo un archivo Square.js que contiene una function:

```
function Square(props) {
    <button className="square" onClick={props.onClick}>
        {props.value}
    </button>
}
```

que vendría el componente funcional que quiero utilizar en otro componente llamado Board.js

Si creo mi archivo Square.js como una clase: `class Square extends from React.Component` utilizando `import Square from './Square.js'` me funciona, pero quiero utilizar un componente funcional.

¿cómo se puede referenciar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A tu función le falta retornar el código que desea mostrar. Tu componente de tipo función puede ser utilizado normalmente desde cualquier otro componente, pero si está en un archivo separado, se deberá guardar la función y exportarla. Ejemplo de cómo quedaría tu archivo `Square.js`:

```
import React from 'react';

const Square = function(props) {
  return (
    <button onClick={props.onClick}>
      {props.value}
    </button>
  );
}

export default Square;
```

El archivo que va a utilizar la función `Square` deberá importarla con:

```
import Square from './Square.js';
```

Ejemplo de un archivo `Board.js` que utiliza un componente de tipo función `Square`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Square from './Square.js';

class Board extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <Square onClick = {() => alert('ejemplo')}
              value = "Nombre del botón" / >
    );
  }
}
```

Si tuvieras todo el código en un solo archivo, quedaría como el siguiente ejemplo ejecutable:

```js
function Square(props) {
  return (
    <button onClick={props.onClick}>
      {props.value}
    </button>
  );
}

class Board extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <Square onClick = {() => alert('ejemplo')}
              value = "Nombre del botón" / >
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( <Board /> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```